# geom_beeswarm with half plot and not symmetry

Tags: r, ggplot2, beeswarm

I am using geom_beeswarm to test the distribution of data in my dataset. In my toy example here, this is my code to do that.

```
library(survival)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggbeeswarm)
data("pbc")
head(pbc)

ggplot(pbc, aes(x=trt, y= age, color = trt)) +
  geom_beeswarm(cex =2, size =3, priority="density") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(), legend.position = "none") + 
  facet_wrap(~trt, nrow = 3, ncol = 1)
```

This is what I get,

[image]

However I am interested in only one half of the plot, not symmetry like shown below. Expected plot

[image]

I know I can accomplish this using the side=1 or side=-1 option in the original beeswarm library. Not sure how to do the same using the geom_beeswarm option. Any suggestion is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: A `side` argument has been added to `geom_beeswarm` in the development version of `ggbeeswarm`. See https://github.com/eclarke/ggbeeswarm.

Comment: @stefan, IL , lol, got it. I was trying 1.